# Highcharts colorsByPoint not working when used with linear gradient in a series

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to set up three different gradient colors -- red, green, and yellow, and then assign those colors to individual data points in my series based on the value. However, when I render the chart, they all default to the whichever color I specify on the first data point in the first series.

Consider this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2UVcD/2/

Try changing the first color in the chartData array to yellowColor or redColor, and you can see what I mean. I have colorbypoint set to true in the plotOptions -- am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`linearGradient` have to be an `array`, not an object.

It should be like the following.

`var perShapeGradient = [0, 0, 1, 0];`

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/2UVcD/3/)